# How to Remove the cells from pandas column where particular string matched

Tags: python, pandas

My current pandas dataframe:

```
       Subject         Test1               Test2               Test3           
       Python           45                 Temp                25              
                        50                 Temp                Temp              
                        Temp                 30                Temp              
                        Temp                 35                Temp                
                        Temp                 38                Temp               
       OS               Temp                Temp                45
                        33                  24                  32      
                        43                  34                  44                                  
                        Temp                43                  31
       Java             33                  32                  34
                        43                  33                  36
```

Expected output:

```
       Subject         Test1               Test2               Test3           
       Python           45                  30                  25              
                        50                  35
                                            38                                                                                                           
       OS               33                  24                  45
                        43                  34                  32      
                                            43                  44                                  
                                                                31
       Java             33                  32                  34
                        43                  33                  36
```

I need to remove cells where 'Temp' matched. Drop whole rows will not work in this case, so I got stuck here. please help.

Comment: I am not getting desired output. can you give me example of code snippets to get desired output.

Comment: I tried this: df= df[~df['Test1'].isin(['Temp'])]. suppose I will remove Temp from all columns then it will lose the data that actually require in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no values in `Subject` are empty string first replace them to missing values and then forward filling them in first step:

```
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].replace('',np.nan).ffill()
```

Then use custom function for remove `Temp` values per groups in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def f(x):
      return x.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x.ne('Temp')].tolist(),name=x.name))

df = (df.set_index('Subject')
        .groupby('Subject', sort=False)
        .apply(f)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())

print (df)
  Subject Test1 Test2 Test3
0  Python    45    30    25
1  Python    50    35   NaN
2  Python   NaN    38   NaN
3      OS    33    24    45
4      OS    43    34    32
5      OS   NaN    43    44
6      OS   NaN   NaN    31
7    Java    33    32    34
8    Java    43    33    36
```

Or after processing `Subject` first unpivot by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), remove `Temp` rows and pivoting with counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for helper column with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['Subject'] = df['Subject'].replace('',np.nan).ffill()

df = df.melt('Subject')
df = df[df['value'].ne('Temp')].copy()
df['g'] = df.groupby(['Subject','variable']).cumcount()

df = (df.pivot(['Subject','g'],'variable','value') 
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
  Subject Test1 Test2 Test3
0    Java    33    32    34
1    Java    43    33    36
2      OS    33    24    45
3      OS    43    34    32
4      OS   NaN    43    44
5      OS   NaN   NaN    31
6  Python    45    30    25
7  Python    50    35   NaN
8  Python   NaN    38   NaN
```

Comment: First solution worked for me on windows platform. I am trying to run this code in ubuntu but it's showing following error: File "/home/romin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2895, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 96, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 126, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates

Comment: @codewarrior - Data are same? Pandas version is same?

Comment: It's resolved now. Problem with splitting the path while taking data. In windows any directory path is spitted using "\\" but for Linux we need to use '/'. Thanks for your support.